# Easy way to compose to Facebook in iOS 5

Tags: facebook, ios5, twitter, ios4, ios6

In iOS 6 there is a compose viewcontroller for Facebook. In its iOS 5 there is the tweetsheet. In ios 4 you could use could use [DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController). My question is, is there something like DETweetComposeViewController for iOS 5 that does Facebook, where I handle the login and so on? If not is there an easy way to compose to facebook other than the dialog functions of the Facebook sdk?

Comment: I feel your pain. Please let me know if you've found a way.

Comment: I have since found this: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/defacebookcomposeviewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, I have found this since: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/defacebookcomposeviewcontroller

You still need to implement the facebook SDK but it handles the looks.

Answer (score 2):

I would wait for iOS6 if I was you, or head over to the Apple Developer's website and get the BETA. Facebook is built right in and posting things to Facebook is a whole lot easier.

Comment: Yes, I have the beta and It works great but, I need something similar in iOS 5

Comment: You'll have to send the user to Facebook, to log in via your App and then you'll be free to post anything to their wall/feed.

Comment: yes but how would I do such a thing? I have already taken  care of login and so on.